# How to connect to MSSQL server hosted on my webserver

Tags: sql-server, ssms, remote-server

I have a windows hosting and MSSQL Server attached with it.
To manage the database my web host provides a freeware.
How do I connect SQL server management Studio installed on my local machine to the remote MSSQL server provided with my web host ? 
Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: This is a very broad question... do you have any additional information that could help us diagnose a specific issue?  What have you tried?

Comment: My webhost provides me with
server name , username and password.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJwpq-lLnWAhXolFQKHcxzCcwQtwIIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DhT9p_FPt720&usg=AFQjCNEh4dLG5PlfIo2XQQHp_LDmZQwkgg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I connect SQL server management Studio installed on my local machine to the remote MSSQL server provided with my web host ?

You don't. It's exceptionally dangerous to expose a production web site database server directly to the public internet.

Where you go from here depends on your host, but generally you do a certain amount of base development on your local system, and when you're far enough to push an initial release you send the mdf file or a backup to the web server along with your site code, and load the database into the Sql Server instance there with your provider's tool.

From that point on you continue development by working with sample data on your local system, disconnected from the production environment. Deployment techniques vary, but one common option is that changes to the database schema or metadata are accomplished by writing *.sql scripts that can be deployed along with new code.